# Transport-Level error when running Invoke-Sqlcmd query, but only when launching from within another function?

Tags: sql, powershell

I get the error below when running the following query to get the name of my AG. "SELECT TOP 1 AG.name FROM sys.availability_groups AG", but only when launching it from within another module.

A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)
Msg 64, Level 20, State 0, Procedure , Line 0.
Error in Line:      Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -Query $query | Select-Object -expand Name

When I call to the .psm that runs this standalone, it runs without fail, but when I call to it from within another .psm it has run twice out of the >50 attempts I have made today.  Any advice or ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: The value of `$ServerName` is possibly not what you're expecting. Diagnosing this would need more context for how you're invoking the code, though. Another issue could be intermittent DNS failures, but those would not occur simply because code is running inside a different module -- at worst it could happen because the code is inadvertently running remotely, but that too would need more context.

Comment: The $ServerName thought went though my head as well, so I added the Write-Host line below.  As you can see though it is pretty simple and straightforward.    Function GetAGName {
 param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][String]$ServerName)
 Write-Host "Getting AG Name from $ServerName"
 $query = 'SELECT TOP 1 AG.name FROM sys.availability_groups AG'

 Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -Query $query | Select-Object -expand Name


}